# How to add Launcher to Global menu Bar

Tags: 12.04, launcher, globalmenu

Im coming from linux Mint. I installed Ubuntu 13.04 but the first thing i noticed is that when I tried to add the launcher of terminal or other application it is not adding that launcher to Global Menu.

[image]

Does any know how to do this

Comment: @SteffenChristensen Please make that an answer as it is, and not a comment.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible. 
That's what the launcher (The "panel" on the left hand side) is for.

Currently you don't have a lot of options to customize Unity, however if you do want to know what you can do, check out the "Unity Tweak Tool" which from 13.04 is available as a free download in the Ubuntu software center.

If you want to do it from terminal then you can do it from

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: Hey you fine with the edit ?

Comment: Of course :) wasn't aware that if was only available from 13.04. And everybody likes terminal. Thank you.

Comment: you're welcome :). keep posting good answers.